# __write_overflow declared with attribute error

Tags: kernel, compiling

I'm using `memset` and `memcpy` in my linux kernel project.
When I've tried to `make` the project, I got the following error:

> In function ‘memset’,
>       inlined from ‘init_minifw_read_write_module’ at /home/ido/CLionProjects/Firewall/KernelSpace/minfirewall.c:118:13:
>   ./include/linux/string.h:327:3: error: call to ‘__write_overflow’ declared with attribute error: detected write beyond size of object passed as 1st parameter
>      __write_overflow();

I didn't find any workaround for the above error.

I've added the `CFLAGS` to my Makefile in order to avoid this issue:

```
obj-m += minfirewall.o
CFLAGS_minfirewall.o := -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=0
all:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) modules
clean:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) clean
```

But the issue is still persist.

I'm running kernel version 4.18.0-15-generic.

Any ideas how to fix this error?

Comment: hi! I'm not sure I've got the best insight to provide but I believe there's this thing with adding stuff to the kernel where generally libs are bleeding edge, do you think it's possible this error might go away with an attempt to compile a more recent version of the kernel, like at least 4.20? is it with 4.18.0-15-generic so as to avoid apt update warning?

Comment: Is there a workaround ?

Comment: well I'm suggesting a workaround : use a higher version kernel as your working copy. But ignore me, more talented people will come around to provide better insight I'm not experienced with kernel compilation. kernel compilation is what you are attempting to do, right?

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to write more bytes to the array than it is capable of holding. I'd check the values of the parameters you are providing to these functions.

Comment: I don't believe this is the right place to ask for assistance for a C project. And you are not sharing any code, either. This is not an Ubuntu specific issue, it's a compiler error. And compilers are very-very smart these days.

Comment: Maybe you can try add `-O0`. `CFLAGS_t.o := -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=0 -O0`